# Why is OpenLayer addFeatures no working?

Tags: javascript, openlayers, shapefile

http://www.cv.nctu.edu.tw/shapefile-js-openlayers/ol_simple.html

This is my website for test.

I want to put shape file in OpenLayer

Then, I find a example.

https://github.com/mattwigway/shapefile-js/tree/openlayers

Try it and put my shape file in OpenLayer

So, use proj4 to convert EPSG:3826 to EPSG:4326

But, I can't addFeature in OpenLayer.

By the way, My shape file's projection is EPSG:3826

Comment: it would be great if you can provide your example code, where you are facing trouble plotting via shape file. also link you provided for test website is not working.